# Custom Emu8086 8-bit Binary Virtual Device debugging

Tags: vba, visual-studio, assembly, virtual, emu8086

I've been trying to code a custom Emu8086 (8086 microprocessor emulator) 8-bit binary virtual device output that displays assembly input as binary output:

MOV AX, 0FFH -> OUTPUT: 1111 1111

I've had success in deriving the UI from the sample virtual device Visual Basic 6.0 source code that displays decimal output from assembly input.

[Original UI from LED_Display Sample Virtual Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYwN.png)

[Derived UI From LED_Display Sample Virtual Device (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7lBu.png)

I had to upgrade the Visual Basic 6.0 source code to Visual Studio 2008 compliant code and thought maybe the problem lies there?

But whenever I debug the code, it works as desired, listening to the port number assigned for assembly input when I launch the emulator and displays the desired binary equivalent numbers.

However, when using the standalone .exe file, it no longer works. I included the IO.VB (io.bas before upgrade) that was necessary to be included as a separate module in one VB file thinking that it might be the culprit to no avail.

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Module io

Const sIO_FILE As String = "C:\emu8086.io"

Function READ_IO_BYTE(ByRef lPORT_NUM As Integer) As Byte
    On Error GoTo err_rib

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim tb As Byte
    Dim fNum As Short

    sFileName = sIO_FILE

    fNum = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(fNum, sFileName, OpenMode.Random, , OpenShare.Shared, 1)

    ' File's first byte has Index 1 in VB
    ' compatibility for Port 0:
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Get was upgraded to FileGet and has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="9B7D5ADD-D8FE-4819-A36C-6DEDAF088CC7"'
    FileGet(fNum, tb, lPORT_NUM + 1)

    FileClose(fNum)


    READ_IO_BYTE = tb


    Exit Function
err_rib:
    Debug.Print("READ_IO_BYTE: " & Err.Description)
    FileClose(fNum)

End Function

Sub WRITE_IO_BYTE(ByRef lPORT_NUM As Integer, ByRef uValue As Byte)
    On Error GoTo err_wib

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim fNum As Short

    sFileName = sIO_FILE

    fNum = FreeFile()


    FileOpen(fNum, sFileName, OpenMode.Random, , OpenShare.Shared, 1)

    ' File's first byte has Index 1 in VB
    ' compatibility for Port 0:
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Put was upgraded to FilePut and has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="9B7D5ADD-D8FE-4819-A36C-6DEDAF088CC7"'
    FilePut(fNum, uValue, lPORT_NUM + 1)

    FileClose(fNum)

    Exit Sub
err_wib:
    Debug.Print("WRITE_IO_BYTE: " & Err.Description)
    FileClose(fNum)
End Sub


Function READ_IO_WORD(ByRef lPORT_NUM As Integer) As Short
    Dim tb1 As Byte
    Dim tb2 As Byte

    ' Read lower byte:
    tb1 = READ_IO_BYTE(lPORT_NUM)
    ' Write higher byte:
    tb2 = READ_IO_BYTE(lPORT_NUM + 1)

    READ_IO_WORD = make16bit_SIGNED_WORD(tb1, tb2)
End Function


Sub WRITE_IO_WORD(ByRef lPORT_NUM As Integer, ByRef iValue As Short)
    Dim tb1 As Byte
    Dim tb2 As Byte

    ' Write lower byte:
    WRITE_IO_BYTE(lPORT_NUM, iValue And 255) ' 00FF
    ' Write higher byte:
    WRITE_IO_BYTE(lPORT_NUM + 1, CShort(iValue And 65280) / 256) ' FF00 >> 8
End Sub

' This function corrects the file path by adding "\"
' in the end if required:
Function AddTrailingSlash(ByRef sPath As String) As String

    If (sPath <> "") Then
        If (Mid(sPath, Len(sPath), 1) <> "\") Then
            AddTrailingSlash = sPath & "\"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    AddTrailingSlash = sPath

End Function

Function make16bit_SIGNED_WORD(ByRef byteL As Byte, ByRef byteH As Byte) As Short
    Dim temp As Integer

    ' lower byte - on lower address!
    ' byte1 - lower byte!

    temp = byteH
    temp = temp * 256 ' shift left by 8 bit.
    temp = temp + byteL


    make16bit_SIGNED_WORD = make_signed_int(temp)
End Function

' Makes a Long to be a SIGNED Integer:
Function make_signed_int(ByRef l As Integer) As Short
    If l >= -32768 And l < 65536 Then
        If l <= 32767 Then
            make_signed_int = l
        Else
            make_signed_int = l - 65536
        End If
    Else
        make_signed_int = 0
        Debug.Print("wrong param calling make_signed_int(): " & l)
    End If
End Function


End Module
```

Here is the code for the virtual device:

```
Friend Class frmLed
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Dim lPrevResult As Integer ' #1122d

Function PrevInstance() As Boolean
    If UBound(Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName _
       (Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName)) _
       > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function


Private Sub frmLed_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' do not allow more than one copy of this program to run simuateniously
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: App property App.PrevInstance was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="076C26E5-B7A9-4E77-B69C-B4448DF39E58"'
    If PrevInstance() Then

        ShowPrevInstance()

        End ' terminate this instance!

    End If

    GetWindowPos(Me)

    If allow_on_top() Then set_on_top(Me)


End Sub

Private Sub frmLed_FormClosed(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    SaveWindowState(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    On Error GoTo err1

    ' Intenger values:
    '    -32,768 to 32,767
    Dim lResult As Integer


    ' Read SIGNED WORD from port 199:
    lResult = READ_IO_WORD(199)


    If lPrevResult <> lResult Then ' #1122d
        If shall_activate(Me) Then Me.Show()
        lPrevResult = lResult
    End If

    ' Show minus if required:
    If lResult < 0 Then
        imgMINUS.Visible = True
        lResult = System.Math.Abs(lResult)
    Else
        imgMINUS.Visible = False
    End If

    ' Display 5 digits:
    Dim i As Short
    Dim v As Byte

    Dim dec, bin As Integer

    For i = 0 To 7

        v = lResult Mod 10

        bin = Fix(lResult) Mod 2

        dig(i).Image = d(bin).Image

        lResult = Int(lResult / 2)

    Next i

    Exit Sub
err1:
    Debug.Print("err1")
    Resume Next
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm confused as to why it works on the IDE debugging state but doesn't work when being run as a .exe file. Any insights would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Visual Basic 6.0 on my computer, altered the sample code there and everything worked out. 
[Virtual Device in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brfyv.gif)